# Backbone.js: undelegateEvents not removing events

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myView">
  <button id="test_button">
    Test Button
  </button>
  <ul id="output"></ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        // why doesn't this remove the previously delegated events?
        this.undelegateEvents();

        this.delegateEvents({
            'click #test_button': 'buttonClicked'
        });
    },

    // this event fires twice for one button click    
    buttonClicked: function() {
        $("#output").append('<li>Button was clicked</li>'); 
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    new myView({el: "#myView"});    

  // instantiate view again
  new myView({el: "#myView"});  
});
```

why does

```
this.undelegateEvents();
```

in the initialize() method of the Backbone View not remove the previously delegated events from the previous instantiation of the View?

JSFiddle example of above code: https://jsfiddle.net/billb123/o43zruea/28/

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do by initializing the View twice. If you want to see undelegateEvents in action, move it after the append inside buttonClicked and instantiate the View once - the click will only be fired once, then the event binding is removed.

Comment: @bdc - I have a Backbone application I'm developing that switches Views by instantiating them in Backbone routes, but this results in events delegated in any particular view firing multiple times depending on how many times the route for that view has instantiated the View (i.e., by the user navigating back and forth between Views without reloading the page).  I thought I could fix this by simply removing any delegated events for the View before re-delegating them.  Plus, I would like to know why my example does what it does - I would think undelegateEvents would do exactly that.

Comment: Calling undelegateEvents before switching routes, outside of initialize() should work for you. The reason it doesn't work inside initialize is because you are instantiating two separate instances of your View. The second instance isn't bound to the events from the first instance. Backbone source: this.$el.off('.delegateEvents' + this.cid). this.cid is unique for each view you instantiate, even if the DOM element is the same.

Comment: Please add the code required to reproduce the issue **in question**. External links should be supplimentary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try not to shout but please stop trying to bind views to existing elements. Let the view create and own its own `el`, then call `view.remove()` to kill it off before replacing it. This simple change solves so many problems with view events that you should always think twice (and twice more) if you don't do it this way.

In your case, you'd have HTML like this:

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-underscore">
  <div id="myView">
    <button id="test_button">
      Test Button
    </button>
  </div>
</script>
<div id="container">
</div>
<ul id="output"> <!-- This is outside the container because we're going to empty and refill it -->
</ul>
```

And your JavaScript would look like this:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click #test_button': 'buttonClicked'
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html($('#t').html());
    return this;
  },
  buttonClicked: function() {
    $("#output").append('<li>Button was clicked</li>'); 
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  var v = new myView();
  $('#container').append(v.render().el);

  v.remove(); // <----------------- Clean things up before adding a new one

  v = new myView();
  $('#container').append(v.render().el);
});
```

Points of interest:

1. Create the view then render it then put it on the page.
2. Call `remove` on the view when you're done with it.
3. The view goes inside the container. The caller owns the container, the view owns its `el`.
4. There are no `delegateEvents` or `undelegateEvents` calls anywhere. The presence of those almost always point to structural problems in your application IMO.
5. Each view is self contained: the outside world doesn't play with anything inside the view and the view keeps its hands to itself.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bp8fqdgm/

---

But why didn't your attempted `undelegateEvents` do anything? [`undelegateEvents` looks like this](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.3.3/backbone.js#L1328):

```
undelegateEvents: function() {
  if (this.$el) this.$el.off('.delegateEvents' + this.cid);
  return this;
},
```

The `cid` is unique per view instance so each view instance uses its own unique namespace for events that `delegateEvents` binds. That means that this:

```
this.undelegateEvents();
this.delegateEvents();
```

is saying:

1. Remove the events that this instance of the view has bound. These events will be found in the the `'.delegateEvents' + this.cid` namespace where `cid` is unique for each view instance.
2. Bind the events that this instance of the view defines (or the events in the `delegateEvents` call). These events will be attached using the `'.delegateEvents' + this.cid` namespace.

So your `undelegateEvents` call is removing events but not all of them, only the specific event bindings that that view *instance* adds are removed.

Your `this.undelegateEvents()` call doesn't actually accomplish anything because it is in the wrong place and called at the wrong time. If the `new View` caller did the `undelegateEvents` call:

```
var v = new myView({el: "#myView"});    
v.undelegateEvents();
new myView({el: "#myView"});
```

then it would happen in the right place and at the right time. Of course this means that your router needs to keep track of the current view so that it can `currentView.undelegateEvents()` at the right time; but if you're doing that then you'd be better off (IMO) taking the approach I outlined at the top of the answer.

Comment: @TJ But it really is the one simple trick that solves almost all view event problems :)